# Returning a text file from a WPF button click

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I am working on a project where I need to generate an iCal file, using iCal.NET, with the WPF framework. The iCal file is to be generated based upon the click of a button event. I have an example of the code, below:

```
private void DownloadiCal_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        var later = now.AddHours(2);

        //Repeat Once a week
        var rrule = new RecurrencePattern(FrequencyType.Weekly, 1) { Count = 1 };

        //Creation of New Calendar Event

        var ce = new CalendarEvent 
        {
            Start = new CalDateTime(now),
            End = new CalDateTime(later),
            RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { rrule },
        };


        //Update to include Calendar event to Calendar. 
        var calendar = new Ical.Net.Calendar(); 
        calendar.Events.Add(ce);

        var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
        var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
        var bytesCalendar = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);

        return File(bytesCalendar, "text/calendar", "event.ics");
}
```

However, upon the button click, the file is not generated, I believe it is related to return File, though, for documentation that I have currently looked at, I see examples for ASP.NET, but not for WPF. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is `void` which means you can't `return` a value from it. Similarly, `File` is a [static class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) which means you can't instantiate it. I think what you ultimately want is [`File.WriteAllText(filePath, serialized)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var savePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Path\to\parent\directory", "event.ics");
File.WriteAllText(savePath, serializedCalendar);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, That has solved my issue at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the file you created, you just sends it to the void by returning it in an event handler. If you want to save it to the disk you could do the following:

```
var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);

using (var stream = new StreamWriter("event.ics"))
{
    stream.Write(serializedCalendar);
}
```

This will create a file with the name "event.ics" in your output folder.